# Vue, Composition API: How to skip deeply nested property from reactive conversion?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In the vue-composition-api:
Using the reactive() method, I would like to keep parts of the object as a reference.

---

I have some products, which are of a custom class:

```
const chair = new Product(...); // lots of information in each product 
const table = new Product(...); // lots of information in each product
```

And a list of orders, which reference a product, in a deep object:

```
let example = reactive({   
  orders: [
    { product: chair, quantity: 2 }, 
    { product: table, quantity: 1 }, 
    { product: chair, quantity: 6 }, 
    { product: table, quantity: 2 },
  ] 
});
```

I checked via `example.orders[0].product == chair` -> `false` that these are different objects.
I also found out that `example.orders[0].product` is not of type Product.

Since I can have lots of different orders and products contain much data, I would like that `example.orders[].product` stays a reference to the original product.

I do not require reactivity for the Products themselves, since these are constant.  (This is an electron app, and the content will be constant for as long as the program runs)

I only would like to have reactivity for the orders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [markRaw](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#markraw):

```
import { markRaw, reactive } from 'vue';

const example = reactive({   
  orders: [
    { product: chair, quantity: 2 }, 
    { product: table, quantity: 1 }, 
    { product: chair, quantity: 6 }, 
    { product: table, quantity: 2 },
  ].map(el => ({ 
    ...el,
    product: markRaw(el.product)
  }))
});
```

*Note:* please read the warning on the label.